# Login failed when using sqlsrv from PHP

Tags: php, sql, wamp

I am trying to set up a WAMP server on Windows 2008 R2.  Have Apache, PHP, and MySQL working.  Issue is concerning connecting to a MS SQL server.  My login fails.

SQLSTATE: 28000
Code: 18456
Message: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'Dataread'.

I am currently running a LAMP server and can log in to the MS SQL server using the same credentials.  I have verified the connection information (TCP, IP address, port).  SQL server is not on this server.  IIS is not running.  The login account is not a Windows account.

```
$serverName = "tcp:192.168.xxx.xxx,1433";  
$connectionOptions = array("Database"=>"[Hill Country MHDD Centers]",  "Uid"=>"Dataread", "PWD"=>"xxxxxxxx");  
        $conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, connectionOptions);
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

After much digging and experimenting, discovered that the bracket around the database name was causing the problem.  Removed them and it works.